# How to interpret effects of predictors with large confidence intervals in GLMM?

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, glmm, effects

(This question is somehow related to my [previous](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394110/which-random-effects-to-include-in-this-glmm) one)

My aim is to find out about which effect several predictors have on my response variable, I am interested in the direction and magnitude of the effect. I am wondering how I should evaluate the effect and if I can ignore the p-values for the estimates for that matter.

My model is a GLMM (Gamma family with inverse link):

```
Response ~ P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P... + (1|Plot) + (1|Year) + (1|Plant ID)
```

[image]

Now to get an idea of the marginal effects of the predictors I plot them using `plot_model` from `sjPlot`:

[image]

Where do I go from here?

Am I okay to ignore p-values from the model and consider the direction and effect of each predictor in order to find out how my response variable is influenced? I. e. can I safely interpret that an increment in P1 or reduction in P2 will increase the response (all other predictors held constant at their means)? How would I deal with and communicate the uncertainty (large confidence intervals)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot simply

> ignore p-values from the model and consider the direction and effect of each predictor

First of all, note the estimated fixed effect coefficients for `P1` and `P2`, -0.042 and 0.025 compared to those for `P3` and `P4`, -0.204 and -1.242 respectively. Are the point estimates -0.042 and 0.025 **practically** significant ?

If we form a 95% confident interval for `P1` as -0.042 +/- 1.96* 0.035, we obtain the interval (-0.1106, 0.0266), so we can be 95% confident that this interval contains the true estimate of the association of `P1` on the outcome. Since this overlaps 0 substantially, you cannot simply ignore the p value and report the effect size, since we cannot be confident that the true effect is positive, negative or zero. A similar argument applies to `P2`: A 95% confidence interval is (-0.066, 0.01616).

If the end points of these confidence intervals are not **practically** significant then it should be OK to simply report these intervals and note that the entire interval is not practically significant.

If the end points of these confidence intervals *are* practically significant, then the best that you can do is simply report the point estimates and the intervals.